# Get equation from glm coefficients: calculate y manually?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, multinomial-logit

I am trying to understand the math behind the `glm()`. Specifically, how to apply equation based on model predictors to calculate my `y.pred`? To fully understand it, I want to calculate my y manually, and apply this equation on the columns of dummy-coded predictors.

Let's have an example:

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

# data source: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/
# treat rank as factor   
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
```

Define logistic regression as `logit`, using `binomial family`:

```
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre *gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = binomial("logit"))
```

Ok, this is how my coefficients looks like:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)          gre          gpa        rank2        rank3        rank4  
 -13.608810     0.018344     3.652170    -0.721697    -1.343466    -1.606298  
    gre:gpa  
  -0.004719
```

And this is the head of my input data:

```
  admit gre  gpa rank predict.admit
1     0 380 3.61    3     0.2191482
2     1 660 3.67    3     0.2948499
3     1 800 4.00    1     0.6398017
4     1 640 3.19    4     0.1886730
5     0 520 2.93    4     0.1029292
6     1 760 3.00    2     0.4522299
```

Following the logic that the predicted value is the sum of `intercept + predictorsXbeta coefficients + beta*x1*x2` to include interactions, I get something like this:

```
 y = a + b1x1 + b2x2 + ... + bnxn + bx1*x2

  admit gre  gpa rank predict.admit
1     0 380 3.61    3     0.2191482
```

Combine the coefficients with the first row of my table:

```
  admit gre  gpa rank
1     0 380 3.61    3

 y = -13.608 +380*0.018 + 3.61*3.652 -1.343*1 - 0.004* 380*3.61
```

**my `y` is -0.41448.**

I thought that this is a `logit(y)` and as such I want to transform it back to probability value: [function here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob)

```
logit2prob <- function(logit){
  odds <- exp(logit)
  prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
  return(prob)
}
```

Let's convert my `y.pred` (-0.41448) to probability:

```
logit2prob(-0.41448)
[1] 0.3978384
```

But, if I run the `predict.glm` on my data, I get a different value:

```
mydata$predict.admit<-predict.glm(mylogit, mydata, type = "response")

admit gre  gpa rank predict.admit
1     0 380 3.61    3     0.2191482   # !! 0.2191482 is not equal to my calculation "-0.41448"??
```

So, I have in fact two questions:

1. How to calculate my `y.predict` manually, from estimated coefficients?
2. How to get `y.predict` for the `rank = 1`, i.e. the reference category, which is missing from the predicted values? is it simply `0`?

My ultimate goal is to create a *vector of coefficients * that I can later on multiply by columns (binary for categorical values, qualitative for others) to predict my `y` manually.  This requires convert the categorical values to binary dummy variables.

EDIT:

This is a full example to manually calculate my `y` using the dummy variables, where I skip the reference categories.

```
# get vector of coefficients
myCoef<- mylogit$coefficients

# get binary variables
mydata.bin <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(mydata,
                                      remove_first_dummy = TRUE)  # remove 

      admit gre  gpa rank rank_2 rank_3 rank_4
1     0 380 3.61    3      0      1      0
2     1 660 3.67    3      0      1      0
3     1 800 4.00    1      0      0      0
4     1 640 3.19    4      0      0      1
5     0 520 2.93    4      0      0      1
6     1 760 3.00    2      1      0      0

# remove not needed columns and add column for interaction
# I do this step to multiply vector of coefficients with individual columns, columnswise
md.bin<-subset(mydata.bin, select = -c(admit, rank))

# add new columns to include intercept and interactions between `gre` and `gpa`
md.bin$interc <- 1
md.bin$gre_gpa = md.bin$gre * md.bin$gpa

# order the dataframe as coefficients order
md.bin<- md.bin[c("interc", 
                  "gre",
                  "gpa",
                  "rank_2",
                  "rank_3",
                  "rank_4",
                  "gre_gpa" )]

# Multiply the vector of coefficients with dataframe
part.md.bin <- sweep(md.bin, 2, myCoef, "*")

# sum by rows and add intercept value
mydata.bin$pred.manual <- logit2prob(rowSums(part.md.bin))
mydata.bin$fitted <- mylogit$fitted.values
```

It seems that my manually predicted values (`pred.manual`), and `fitted` values are the same (at some precision). I wonder if this means that my manual calculation is correct?

Comment: Your manual calculation is correct in terms of the coefficients, but you lose precision by either rounding incorrectly (i.e. the coefficient of the interaction) or by just not using enough numbers after the decimal point. Try the manual calculation again but use more precise coefficients values.

Comment: @COOLSerdash, wow, you are right! it was just because of not enough precise coefficients applied! now I will get my `y` as `logit2prob(-1.270747)` and this corresponds to expected value `0.2191294`. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manual calculation is correct in terms of the coefficients, but you lose precision by either rounding incorrectly (i.e. the coefficient of the interaction) or by just not using enough numbers after the decimal point. Here is the manual calculation using 5 significant digits:
$$
\mathrm{logit}(y) = -13.609 + 0.018344\cdot 380 + 3.6522\cdot 3.61 - 1.3435\cdot 1 -0.004719\cdot 380\cdot 3.61 = -1.270862
$$
The corresponding probability is:
$$
\exp(-1.270862)/(1 + \exp(-1.270862)) = 0.2191
$$

Which is in good agreement with the more precise result from `predict` which uses the full precision available.

**Edit**

What if instead of the prediction for `rank3` we'd like to predict for an individual with `rank1` which is the reference value of the categorical variable `rank`? In the current dummy coding scheme, the coefficients for `rank2`-`rank4` are the *differences* in the log-odds between the reference category and the respective level. Thus, the coefficient for the reference category is the intercept. Hence, the predicted log-odds in this situation are simply:

$$
\mathrm{logit}(y) = -13.609 + 0.018344\cdot 380 + 3.6522\cdot 3.61 -0.004719\cdot 380\cdot 3.61 = 0.0726378
$$
and the corresponding probability is $0.5181515$.

Comment: please, can you also specify how to get a coefficient for a reference categorical variable? i.e. for `rank1`?

Comment: @maycca I've added a short section. In essence, the coefficient of `rank1` is the intercept.

Comment: maybe I can just even skip the reference category from the prediction, as it always will be 0?

Comment: @@COOLSerdash, just to confirm: if the `rank1` is the intercept, can I include it in my equation as 0? ie. `y = intercept + b1*gre + b2*gpa + b3*rank1 + b4*rank2 ...`? The think is that I need to create a vector of coefficients to multiply individual columns (predictors) within the data frame. Or, can I just skip the reference values completely, as it is always 0?

Comment: @maycca No, `rank1` has no associated coefficient. Its coefficient is the intercept. I have shown the equation for `rank1` in my edit.

Comment: thank you. BUt in your update, the coefficient is missing, I would expect something like `rank1*intercept` or `rank1 * 0` (= no added value in sum of predictors). The thing is that I have ordered vector of coefficients and ordered predictors in a dataframe. So, in that case I need to specify coefficient value (even if it is zero) for the rank1?

Comment: @maycca Maybe it's better to say that `rank1` has no coefficient. That's probably less confusing. The coefficient of the ranks are the *differences* between the reference category, which is `rank1` here and the other `rank`s. As the ranks are dummy-coded, `rank1` is when all the dummy-variables for all other ranks are $0$.

Comment: ok, it is getting clearer to me. Please, can you check my edits, if my question make more sense now?

Comment: @maycca Yes, that's correct.